# Insightly PHP API

Tags: php, insightly

I'm using https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php
and having a problem passing a simple variable to a method in it:

```
require("insightly.php");
$i = new Insightly('my-base64-encoded-api-key');
```

Do you know why `getContacts()` doesn't seem to see the variable `$lastname` here?

Example:

```
$lastname = $_GET["lastname"];
$contacts = $i->getContacts(array("filters" => array('LAST_NAME=\'$lastname\'')));
```

If I hard code a name in the array for example:

```
$contacts = $i-getContacts(array("filters" => array('LAST_NAME=\'Smith\'')));
```

it accepts it and returns results,

but with the variable `$lastname` it returns nothing - and there is no error so it must not see it. - It's probably a syntax error on my part but I would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Try using quotation marks (`""`) instead of apostrophes. This may be the problem because PHP interprets anything in apostrophes literally. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Also, switch on error reporting as those lines should produce errors.

Comment: @vascowhite what errors would there be besides `$i-getContacts` which I assume is just a typo?

Comment: @andrewtweber `array('LAST_NAME=\'$lastname\'')` isn't valid syntax is it?

Comment: Then again, maybe it is https://3v4l.org/qBlD2. My bad. Didn't process the \'s

Answer (score 0):

Because you used apostrophes when setting the array, PHP will interpret it as literal text.
Because of this, the array would read:

```
Array ( [filters] => Array ( [0] => LAST_NAME='$lastname' ) )
```

`$contacts` should be defined like this:

```
$contacts = $i->getContacts(array("filters" => array("LAST_NAME=$lastname")));
```

See [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for more information.

Comment: I tried this syntax : 
$contacts = $i->getContacts(array("filters" => array("LAST_NAME=$lastname"))); 
and get : 400 Bad Request
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax